# Can chances of winning 4 matches be greater than 3 matches

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

The Hockey team for California is visiting Florida to play a series comprising five
matches. 
In each match, assume that the California has a $70\%$ chance of winning.
Further, assuming that the matches are independent of each other, what is the
probability that:

a. The California will win $3$ matches in the series
b. The California will win $4$ matches in the series

As per me, the solution to the above is:

- Probability of team wining $3$ matches:
  $${5 \choose 3} \left(\dfrac{3}{10}\times\dfrac{3}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}\right) = \dfrac{10* 3087}{100000} = 0.3087$$
- Probability of team wining 4 matches:
  $${5 \choose 4} \left(\dfrac{3}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}\right) = \dfrac{5\times 7203}{100000} = 0.36015$$

It turns out that winning probability for $4$ matches is more than winning $3$ matches. That sounds little confusing, as for a layman chances for winning $3$ matches should be greater than $4$ matches.

Is the above solution even correct ? Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Suppose California's chance of winning of a single match is 99.999999%. Is it more likely that they win 5 matches, or exactly 4? Of course if you are asking about winning "at least 3" and "at least 4" then your calculation needs to be different.

Comment: To be clear:  you mean the probability of winning $\textit {exactly}$ $3$ matches?  If so, there is no reason for that to be less than the probability of winning $\textit {exactly} $$4$ matches.  Usually, though, asking in casual speech about the probability of winning $3$ matches refers to $\textit {at least}$ three.

Comment: The probability of winning **at least** $4$ matches is less than the probability of winning **at least** $3$ matches. But in your computations you are dealing with **exactly** here, so not with **at least**.

Comment: Thanks All. I think I now understand the concept. @MichalAdamaszek, your comment makes it really clear.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comment, the question was apparently due to a failure to distinguish between **at least** $n$ matches and **exactly** $n$ matches. There is no contradiction between the fact that the probability to win at least $n$ matches is greater or equal than the probability to win at least $n+1$ matches and the fact that in some cases the probability to win exactly $n+1$ matches is greater than the  probability to win exactly $n$ matches.